# Return only 1 | 0 | -1 | 2 in a function - TypeScript

Tags: typescript

It's possible to limit the returns values in this way?

```
  comprobarExistencias():   -1 | 0 | 1 | 2  {

    let valor: -1  = -1
    // I don't want do this...

   return valor

  }
```

And don't use the number like a type?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks, but that means I need four return statements, so my complexity plugin will fire ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was more simple than I been thinking

```
let valor: -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 =   1  //This pass
let valor: -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 =   3  //This return and error
```

Now I can use `valor` in all the function. I need to use the number as type but only one time.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this exists is because typescript automatically types things in anticipation for mutation, if let valor = -1 was type `-1` then if you try and change it in the future say valor = 1 you would get the type error 1 is not assignable to type -1;

To get around this typescript 3.5.1 offers the "as const" modifier that tells typescript that your intention is not to modify the value in which case it can be inferred as it's literal type.

```
const negative = -1 as const;
```

Yes, this is extra work to make it infer as -1 however, as mentioned above if it was -1 by default it would lead to way more problems for 90% of the Typescript community.

Comment: `const valor = -1` also works, or putting the union in a type alias and doing `const valor: ResultUnion = -1`

Comment: `if it was -1 by default it would lead to way more problems for 90% of the Typescript community.` would it really though...? If the code was written well, the type narrowing wouldn't suddenly make it fail to compile, but IDE tooltips may just be annoyingly specific about types if this was the default behavior.

Comment: Yes it would, think about it
`let hello = {name: "shanon"}
hello.name = "john doe" // error john doe is not assignable to "shanon"`
this would be what would happen if types were inferred always as their literal types, the only reason you'd want this to be the default is if you entire project is immutable.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's easy to come up with a contrived example where type narrowing would cause a compile error when attempting to mutate a property. However, as I said, well-written code would not incur this issue. In your example, it would be best practice to either provide a type declaration for `hello` such as `type Hello = { name: string }; let hello: Hello = { name: 'sharon' };`, or there would simply be no need to mutate the `hello` object, and return it from a function with a return type of `Hello`, in which case the type-widening would be valid and compile without error.